# Display name from array in auto-complete search bar

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to auto-complete a search bar from a table `remedy` with the string `remedyName`.

Here is the JavaScript I have in `\pages\home.html.erb`

```
 $(function() {
    var availableTags = "<%= @remedies_remedyName%>";

    $( "#autoComplete" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
```

Here is the code in `Pages Controller`

```
def home
 @remedies = Remedy.all
end
```

Here is the html in `/pages/home`

```
<div class="carousel-caption searchbar">                
<form class="search" action="/pages/searchremedy" method="get">
  <input id="autoComplete" class="searchTerm" name="searchremedy"  placeholder=" Search by treatment type, or tell us what you'd like to treat..." />
  <input class="searchButton" type="submit" placeholder="Search" />
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Try https://github.com/peterwillcn/rails4-autocomplete. This will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I got it all setup yesterday but it just didn't seem to work. Auto completion  works for when I have a defined static array, just want to do the same except calling on a array from my table.

Comment: Paste the code of /pages/searchremedy action

Comment: It seems to me that you are trying to output a Ruby array as an array in Javascript. If so, you should post a question that way.

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma the /pages/searchremedy action is a separate. That is a way of searching for something based on remedy typed in and submitted.

Comment: @MladenJablanović Yes that is correct, I was trying to think of  a better way to phrase the title. But you can tell by the structure that's what I meant. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Fergus: I want to see what array u r returning

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma That would be from the id="autoComplete". The array looks like this at the moment. #&lt;Remedy:0xa041450&gt; #&lt;Remedy:0xa041330&gt; #&lt;Remedy:0xa0411b0&gt; #&lt;Remedy:0xa040f70&gt; [#&lt;Remedy id: nil, remedyName: &quot;Acne&quot;&gt;, #&lt;Remedy id: nil, remedyName: &quot;Dark&quot;&gt;, #&lt;Remedy id: nil, remedyName: &quot;House&quot;&gt;, #&lt;Remedy id: nil, remedyName: &quot;Dog&quot;&gt;]

Comment: There is a problem in your search, try  Remedy.where(:name => params[:name]).pluck(:name)

Comment: @FergusMorton take a look at, for example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8375059/ruby-array-to-javascript-array http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210798/ruby-array-to-javascript-rails etc

Comment: @ChakreshwarSharma No the searchbar works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing out Ruby variable `@remedies_remedyName` into your javascript. It does not look like you have defined this instance variable.

```
var availableTags = "<%= @remedies_remedyName%>";
```

Update your js code to the following:

```
var availableTags = "<%= raw(@remedies.map(&:remedyName)).html_safe %>";
```

Note: I am assuming you have column named `remedyName` in your `Remedy` table.

Comment: I thought this would do it but still not working! But yes, you are correct remedyName is a column.

Comment: I've just tried and it worked just fine. Please paste this line from the rendered page here.

Comment: Oh yeah? Which line?

Comment: This one - `var availableTags = `.

Comment: Are you asking to output the array somewhere to see what's in it? I'm new to JS so I'm actually not sure how to do that?

Comment: Just open your page in the browser, `View source` and find that bit.

Comment: Oh my bad, sure thing - var availableTags = "["Car"]";

Comment: Yes! It is working, the quotes around the ruby weren't necessary and now it's working fine. Thank you! You da man

Answer (score 0):

Try the below :

```
var availableTags = <%= @remedies.pluck(:remedyName) %>;
```